# Preload layout with Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial

My application has to do a rather time-consuming operation only on the first 'show' action of the page. 
I have a certain layout in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` that I would like to show from the very first second, so that a spinner alongside with an informative message would be inside this layout, letting the user know that the operation will take some time to finish. After this operation is finished, I would like to substitute this message by the real content, if possible changing this via AJAX, but I would not mind to just refresh the page for the time being.

I have this in my show action, the costly process is 'load_suggestions' (around 5sec).

```
respond_to do |format|
      format.html do
        if @issue.suggestions == [] 
          load_suggestions
        end
      end
      format.xml  { render :xml => @issue }
      format.js   
      end
```

I believe that this post - [Show loading screen while performing task in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831755/show-loading-screen-while-performing-task-in-rails-3) - has some rather interesting information for what I try to accomplish. Basically I would include this javascript function in `views/issues/show.js.erb`. Problem is that if I include it there, it would get called every single time, and that is not what I intend it to do.

Any suggestions, clues, guidance?

Answer (score 0):

you could try out the new [rails streaming api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html) and render some waiting javascript code before the rest of your stuff get's loaded.

i would not consider your approach a good idea. instead i would try to put the slow stuff in the background and use ajax to retrieve it after it finished.

another approach would be to do some "warmup" where you load the stuff before your application is launched. in an initializer for example.

Comment: I'm using Rails 3, any possible way to do streaming with that? That sounds pretty awesome

Comment: Rails 3.what? it was introduced with rails 3.1 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html